# Gitlab not sending email

Tags: email, docker, smtp, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I've installed gitlab ce on docker with the documentation, everything is ok but mails doesn't works in gitlab (ask for new password for example).

When I test my conf in the rail-console I get the mail, when gitlab is supposed to send email, it doesn't works.

For mail I use OVH SMTP conf, my smtp_settings.yml is ok
see by yourself :

```
# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

if Rails.env.production?
  Gitlab::Application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    authentication: :login,
    address: "ssl0.ovh.net",
    port: 465,
    user_name: "myemail@domain.dn",
    password: "mypassword",
    domain: "ssl0.ovh.net",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    tls: true,

    openssl_verify_mode: "peer",

    ca_file: "/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem",
  }
end
```

I already tried openssl_verify_mode: "peer" and "none"

Any idea ? I'm on it from about a month.